# SQLAlchemy: is there an equivalent to metadata.create_all() for schemas?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there an easy solution with SQLAlchemy (declarative system) to have the necessary database schemas built analog to how `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)` works for tables? My solution is the function below, but I was wondering if there is something easier/built-in? I guess there's also better ways to get the schema names than taking them from the table names as I do.

```
def create_schemas(engine):
    table_names = Base.metadata.tables.keys()
    all_schemas = set([t.split('.')[0] for t in table_names if len(t.split('.')) > 1])
    inspector = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(engine)
    existing_schemas = inspector.get_schema_names()
    for s in all_schemas:
        if not s in existing_schemas: engine.execute(CreateSchema(s))
```